# Slicing lists according to another list

Tags: python-3.x

I need to slice list of nucleotide sequences eg. ["ATGCTGACTGCA", "ATGCAGGCGTAG"] according to two other list, one with the start codon and one with the stop codon.

I have all my data in a pandas dataframe, and extracted it into a np array for the sequence and two lists for the start and stop. I've tried with list comprehension:

```py
seq = ["ATGCTGACTGCA", "ATGCAGGCGTAG"]
start = [1, 4]
stop = [6, 12]

[sublist[x:y] for x in start for y in stop for sublist in seq]
```

I tought this would associate the start and end of the sequence I needed and slice the sequence, but the result is a combination (the new list has 8 entries)
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: My expected result would be ["TGCTG","AGGCGTAG"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need one of the following two cases:

A nested loop with a zip, in case you want to get the two sublists for each sequence:

```
[sublist[x:y] for x,y in zip(start,stop) for sublist in seq]
```

Having the following result:

```
['TGCTG', 'TGCAG', 'TGACTGCA', 'AGGCGTAG']
```

Or just a zip with all:

```
[sublist[x:y] for x,y,sublist in zip(start,stop,seq)]
```

Getting the following result:

```
['TGCTG', 'AGGCGTAG']
```

Comment: Thank you, it's the second case :)

Comment: Great @Giu! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `zip` instead of a nested loop.

```
>>> [s[x:y] for x, y in zip(start, stop) for s in seq]
['TGCTG', 'TGCAG', 'TGACTGCA', 'AGGCGTAG']
```